# C# Socket Server Continuously Reading

Tags: c#, sockets

I just made a C# socket server and it works perfectly, but if I would like to make it to be able to listen the inputs the program crashes. My question is: how can I make to continuously listen after the clients commands.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace mc_server
{
    class Program
    {
        private static TcpListener serverSocket;
        private static TcpClient clientSocket;
        private static StreamReader reader;
        private static StreamWriter writer;
        private static int PORT = 5000;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {                
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " >> Server starting...");
            StartServer();
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            serverSocket.Stop();
        }

        private static void StartServer()
        {
            try
            {
                serverSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, PORT);
                serverSocket.Start();
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " >> Server started");
                while (true)
                {
                    clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
                    reader = new StreamReader(clientSocket.GetStream());
                    writer = new StreamWriter(clientSocket.GetStream());
                    StartListening();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (!System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
                    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " [ERR]: Internet connection unavailable! (" + e.ToString() + ")");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " [ERR]: Server can't be started! (" + e.ToString() + ")");
            }
        }

        private static void StartListening()
        {
            try
            {
                string line; 
                //while (true)
                //{
                    line = reader.ReadLine();

                    if (line.Contains("connected"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " >> Remote connected");
                    }
                    else if (line.Contains("get_dir"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("in_get_dir");
                        foreach (string directory in     Directory.GetDirectories(path))
                        {
                            DirectoryInfo dir_name = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
                            string dirName = dir_name.Name;
                            writer.WriteLine(line);
                        }
                    }
                //}
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " [ERR]: " + e.ToString() + ")");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you so much for your help!
Regards, Stanley.

Comment: So what "works perfectly" if it "crashes"? Which exception? Source line of failure? Stacktrace?

Comment: Sorry if I was vague. I meant it works perfectly when the while loop is not active in the StartListening() method. If I put to work it the program crashes at first if statement. But I realize why it crashed, because if I don't send anything the line will be a null pointer and it can't be comparable. So the solution is to insert the commant handler part to and if that not allows to check the command it the line is null. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> I just made a C# socket server and it works perfectly, but if I would like to make it to be able to listen the inputs the program crashes.

I am not sure what you meant by that, but I think you have a problem in receiving/reading the response.

---

```
serverSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, PORT);
            serverSocket.Start();
```

You've created a TcpListener named 'serverSocket'. Now let's create a socket that helps us send and receive data between the server and the client. Creating a Streamwriter and Streamreader is too long and complicated. You'll have to deal with flushing, disposing, and closing them.

---

**Here's my 3 simplified guide of using Socket to communicate:**

**1.) Creating a Socket:**

```
        Socket socket = serverSocket.AcceptSocket(); // This is a                 
//synchronous function. It will not execute the next line until a client 
//connects to the server
```

**2.) Sending data:**

```
        socket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("I am sending a short text to         
the client")); // This will send the text to client. It ONLY accepts byte 
//array, therefore we have to convert it from string to byte array to be 
//able 
//to send it.
```

**3.) Receiving/Reading Data:**

```
        // For Receiving Text from the Client
        byte[] responseByteArray = new byte[socket.ReceiveBufferSize]; // 
//This will create a byte array to store the data. socket.ReceiveBufferSize 
//will tells us the length of the data sent in byte array (not string yet)
        int responseLength = socket.Receive(responseByteArray);  // Tells us 
//the length of the response in byte array (not string yet)
        string response = null; // We will create a variable 'response' to 
//store the final result of the conversion
        for (int i = 0; i < responseLength; i++) // Loop to convert All byte 
//from byte array to string
        {
            response = response + (char)responseByteArray[i]; // Converts 
//every single byte of character to char
        }
        Console.WriteLine(response); // Prints out the final result in 
//string
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You can use async/await keywords to read & write data asynchronously on the sockets.
That way, your input logic will stay separate. If you use async/await, you won't have to manage threads manually.